# auto-close="outsideClick" doesn't work in tablet

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have the following code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <span class="dropdown" dropdown auto-close="outsideClick" dropdown-append-to-body>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
        Click me for a dropdown, yo!
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Element 1</li>
        <li>Element 2</li>
      </ul>
    </span>
  </body>

</html>
```

auto-close="outsideClick" doesn't work in tablet. What do I do?

Basically, I am trying to do something like this:

```html
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 btn-group " dropdown dropdown-append-to-body
                auto-close="outsideClick">
                <button id="btn-append-to-body" type="button" class="btn btn-primary " dropdown-toggle>
                   abcd
                    <span class="caret caret-span"
                        ></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-label" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body"
                    >
```

Answer (score 0):

Add dropdown-menu as well as dropdown.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4444

**UPDATE**

In regards to your update, you may want to be careful mixing the col- styles to the same drop-down directive.

I assume you are using `angular-ui bootstrap`?

Your code does not seem to match the documentation. I think perhaps you're mixing `bootstrap` and `angular-ui bootstrap`.

**Please read:**

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ under dropdown menu.

Comment: I am using this : <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 btn-group " dropdown dropdown-append-to-body
                 id="ddlResorts" auto-close="outsideClick">, still no use. Should I be using dropdown class as well?